# How to upgrade an old Linux box with this hardware configuration?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, memory, upgrade

I have an old Linux box that needs to be upgraded without touching the processor or motherboard. It contains software that was licensed specifically to this physical unit and I have no option other than trying to upgrade it so it performs better.

It is a Dell Precision 360 (`Bios version A04, 01/15/2004`) running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I suppose one first step would be to use an older version of Ubuntu, as its footprint seems to enlarge at each new iteration.

But how about the hard drive and memory?

It is currently using a [40GB Western Digital Caviar](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822140118) that I think could use an upgrade. But how can I be sure a new drive will be compatible (eg SSD)? (Same for RAM).

Here is my config output via `lshw -short`

```
H/W path           Device      Class       Description
======================================================
                               system      Mini Tower Computer
/0                             bus         0W2563
/0/0                           memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/400                         processor   Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz
/0/400/700                     memory      16KiB L1 cache
/0/400/701                     memory      1MiB L2 cache
/0/1000                        memory      512MiB System Memory
/0/1000/0                      memory      256MiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)
/0/1000/1                      memory      256MiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)
/0/1000/2                      memory      DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns) [empty]
/0/1000/3                      memory      DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns) [empty]
/0/100                         bridge      82875P/E7210 Memory Controller Hub
/0/100/1                       bridge      82875P Processor to AGP Controller
/0/100/1/0                     display     NV5 [Vanta / Vanta LT]
/0/100/6                       generic     82875P/E7210 Processor to I/O Memory Interface
/0/100/1d                      bus         82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d.1                    bus         82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1e                      bridge      82801 PCI Bridge
/0/100/1e/c        eth0        network     82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1f                      bridge      82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) LPC Interface Bridge
/0/100/1f.1        scsi0       storage     82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) IDE Controller
/0/100/1f.1/0      /dev/sda    disk        40GB WDC WD400BB-75DE
/0/100/1f.1/0/1    /dev/sda1   volume      36GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1f.1/0/2    /dev/sda2   volume      509MiB Extended partition
/0/100/1f.1/0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume      509MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
/0/100/1f.1/1      /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD_RW ND-3540A
/0/100/1f.2                    storage     82801EB (ICH5) SATA Controller
/0/100/1f.3                    bus         82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                    multimedia  82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller
```

Memory

```
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1000
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 512MiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)
         physical id: 0
         slot: CHANNEL A DIMM 0
         size: 256MiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 333MHz (3.0ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)
         physical id: 1
         slot: CHANNEL B DIMM 0
         size: 256MiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 333MHz (3.0ns)
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns) [empty]
         physical id: 2
         slot: CHANNEL A DIMM 1
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 333MHz (3.0ns)
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns) [empty]
         physical id: 3
         slot: CHANNEL B DIMM 1
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 333MHz (3.0ns)
```

Comment: Your board stats say it has a SATA controller ICH5 so any SSD will attach.  It may be a SATA 1 controller and you may max at 150 +/- mb/s but they will work.

Comment: good point - is there a way of know if I'm on SATA 1 or 2?

Comment: You either replace all the memory or match the timings of the existing memory as close as possible or with lower numbers.  Look for a writing similiar to this CAS 5 4-4-10 on the memory chips.  If you replace all the memory as long as you match the DDR version you should be ok.

Comment: The below 1ms response time of an SSD will make it faster than any hard drive.

Comment: however, the controller is likely to not be able to take full advantage of the SSD. A modern hdd, or raid array might be a better bet here, IMO

Comment: @Jeremy Sturdivant says it support 4gb of DDR 400. So buy qty 4 1gb ddr-400 memory chips.

Comment: @torr that controller is to my knowledge a SATA 1 controller, but any drive should fall back to 150MB/s without issues.

Comment: @JeremySturdivant + cybernard - got it, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard drive installed in your machine currently is an IDE drive, which does not bode well for upgrading to an SSD, however it does have a SATA controller. Any SATA SSD should work just fine, though you may need to configure your BIOS for Parallel ATA emulation.

You may also benefit from adding RAM to the machine, as 512MB is around the lower limit for modern Linux distributions, and that motherboard (Dell W2563) supports up to 4GB of DDR-400 memory.

Comment: thx jeremy - my HDD is 7200 RPM 2MB Cache - this RPM still seems to be what sells nowadays - would other HDD specs make a noticeable difference if I get a new 7200 RPM drive?

Comment: rotational speed has some relevance to speed, but most consumer drives are 7200 RPM. More important is seek speed, cache size, etc.

Your drive has a mere 2MB cache, but a speedy 8.9ms average seek time. A larger cache could help greatly, but if 40GB of size is within your requirements I'd personally suggest an SSD, and in either case I'd avoid bringing in a new IDE drive.

Comment: It should also be noted that capacity itself can affect speed, depending how it's added.  Increasing the number of platters in the drive won't help much, but the increased data density needed for a larger capacity on the same number of platters makes each revolution "worth" more data, so that it can operate at the same angular speed but still have faster transfer rates.

Comment: Jeremy my ram specs says 333MHz clock. OK if I buy 400 MHz DDR400?

Comment: @torr Your current RAM is DDR-333, but your motherboard supports up to DDR-400. Replacing your DDR-333 with DDR-400 should provide a refreshing burst of speed to memory access :-)

Answer (score 2):

The really tricky thing here is that the system is so old that the world has passed on most of the technology in use on this system. Your current hard drives are pata - most modern systems are SATA. You may be able to add a sata controller card - a pci one, and pci-e is the current common standard and use raid for better performance or simply use the on board sata adaptor. *This* is the most important, reliability related change you *must* make, since drives die.

And yes, this supports old school PCI, not PCIe (which the 470 seems to support), so any addons NEED to be for that.

Even with this card, an SSD would be overkill, but if you can boot, you have a modern, maintainable, readily available hard drive installed, rather than the museum piece thats inside right now. This is the only modern component you can use. Luckily, this is the part thats most likely to fail and be a pain in the rear. If you end up getting a 'better' card, you might want to go raid 0 for better performance

I'd try to cannibalize some systems to max out the ram if possible - the ram is DDR, and we're just about to move from DDR3 to 4

As for the OS? I'd try to go with debian (which is pretty slim). If you need X and ubuntu, go with one of the lighter builds, like xubuntu or lubuntu , and the LTS version. Outdated Oses are security risks, and a pain to maintain.

Of course, the details depends on your needs and budget. You could probably *buy* ram for example, and go nuts with the sata card.

Comment: The workstation has a SATA controller already, so no need for an expansion card.

Comment: True - but I was considering the possibility of using it raided. I also missed the fact that it had a sata controller initially ;p

Answer (score 1):

If the CPU & mainboard cannot be touched but you're able to upgrade RAM and harddrive (w/o breaking the license), I'd recommend doing exactly that. More memory and a faster disk will definitely help. As to finding the right disks: you have a SATA controller, so get a SATA drive (probably SATA-I, check the SATA controller specs to be sure). Ubuntu 12.04 supports SSD drives, so this should work as well. Also, look up the specs of your motherboard to get the right memory modules. `lshw` said "SDRAM Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)", but it might be good to look up the specs anyway to find out what configurations / max size of memory is supported.

Also, I'd recommend **against** downgrading to an older distribution, as those will (soon) be end-of-life and might not get important upgrades any more.

Comment: I'm adding the full blown `lshw` listing of memory on OP, let me know what you think. thanks!